# Internal Server Error 500 Asp.net WebApi trying to DI with Entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am building an ASP.net WebApi, and trying to use Entity alongside. I am following this guide.

[Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

I am receiving a 500 internal server error using Fiddler. The JSON Exception message states `ExceptionMessage=An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'LocationsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.`

> Here is the Controller.cs

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Locations")]
public class LocationsController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    private IlocationsRepository LocationsRepo;

    public LocationsController(IlocationsRepository _repo)
    {
        if (_repo == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("_repo"); }
        LocationsRepo = _repo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Location> GetAll()
    {
       return LocationsRepo.GetAll();
    }
}
```

I can't use a parameterless public constructor because I need to use the Database Repository that was created for `Locations`. I verified the issue was with the `IlocationsRepository` by doing the following.

When I replace the `LocationsController` constructor with no parameters , and declare a `List<Location>` within the controller, and use dummy data. I receive a `200` with all the json data correct.

> Here is the start of the Global.asax.cs file

```
 public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
 {
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
 }
```

It seems as if I need to do the dependency injection in the Global, but none of the guides had any information regarding this part.

> For posterity here is the ContextDB cs

```
public class WebServerContext : DbContext
{
    public WebServerContext() : base("WebServerContext") {}
    public DbSet<Order> dOrders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> dLocations { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

> For additional posterity, here is the Locations Repository.

```
public class LocationsRepository : IlocationsRepository
{
    private z_Data.WebServerContext db = new z_Data.WebServerContext();

    public void Add(Location item)
    {
        db.dLocations.Add(item);
    }
    public IEnumerable<Location> GetAll()
    {
        return db.dLocations;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your DI code?

Comment: This seems to be what I am lacking, and I am not using Unity.

Comment: Unless you use ASP.NET vNext alias Core, you need a DI provider like Unity or something else...

Comment: Which DI container are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Dependency Injection for Web Api tutorial on MSDN](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection), you are missing the line to register the dependency resolver (a concrete class that implements `System.Web.Http.IDependencyResolver`) with Web Api. It acts like a bridge between your DI container and Web Api so it can resolve your constructor dependencies.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container); // <- You need this

    // Other Web API configuration not shown.
}
```

Of course, that assumes you are using Unity. If not, you should either use the DependencyResolver that came with your DI container or implement your own.

> **NOTE:** With some DI containers, you also need to register all of your controllers explicitly.

Comment: Does Entity have a resolver then? I think this is what I am missing, I did this for the Mapping of attributes. Any hints?

Comment: No, Entity Framework is an Object to Relational Mapper (for databases). It has nothing at all to do with DI. You need to pick one of the many DI containers to use (although I wouldn't recommend Unity or Ninject because they are both difficult to configure, but Autofac, SimpleInjector, and StructureMap are good options).

Comment: I used SImpleInjector as Unity seemed to have too much overhead. Thank you.